# problem with using extract php function?

Tags: php, function, extract

```
 <?php  
 function check($user_id, $topic_id){

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, topic_id FROM sa where topic_id='$topic_id' and user_id='$user_id'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query)==1){



           return 'you have already voted';
        }
        else {

            $against = ' <li>
    <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="against" title="against">
      <i></i><span>Against</span></button>
          </li>';

            $support ='<li>
            <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="support" title="support">
                <i></i>
                <span>Support</span>
            </button>
        </li>';
            return compact('support', 'against');
        }

extract(check($_SESSION['user_id'], $topicId));

  echo $against;
  echo $support;
?>
```

i keep getting this error:

```
Warning: extract() [function.extract]: First argument should be an array
```

Comment: You are missing a bracket and are you sure that your function executes the second `return` statement?

Comment: where am i missing the bracket

Comment: Before `extract`... but only if you don't want to write a recursive function (which I assume you don't ;)) The bracket before `extract` only closes the `else` block. You need another one to finish the function `check`. And the code is bad design anyway. What do you do if the first `return` statement is executed? Your code will fail.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to add it in here, but its in my real code, well the first executes, the second one gives me the error?

Comment: i was thinking shall i return an array instead this compact function. could i possible do that

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If `retrun 'you have already voted';` is executed, `check` obviously does not return an array, but `extract` is expecting one.

Comment: `compact` returns an array, the problem is the first `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is better:

```
function check($user_id, $topic_id){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, topic_id FROM sa where topic_id='$topic_id' and user_id='$user_id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
       return array('error'=>'you have already voted');
    }
    else {
        $against = ' <li>
<button type="submit" value="Actions" class="against" title="against">
  <i></i><span>Against</span></button>
      </li>';

        $support ='<li>
        <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="support" title="support">
            <i></i>
            <span>Support</span>
        </button>
    </li>';
        return compact('support', 'against');
    }
}

$result = check($_SESSION['user_id'], $topicId);

if(isset($result['error'])) {
    echo $result['error'];
}
else {
    echo $result['against'];
    echo $result['support'];
}
```

You could also consider to use [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Answer (score 3):

The `extract` function expects an array.  You're passing it the results of your `check` function, which is sometimes an array

```
return compact('support', 'against');
```

but sometimes a string.

```
return 'you have already voted';
```

So, I imagine you're seeing the error when the first return statements is executed.

Answer (score 0):

First, function definition is not closed in your code (no closing "}")

Second, your function returns string if user has already voted - in this case PHP would obviously say "First argument should be an array" on extract() function call.

Generally, I'd recommend not to use compact-extract construction, but use structures or associative arrays as return value instead. In this case behavior would be much clearer.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. I'd recommend to use structure or associative array as return value. Structure may have field "status", which may denote, whether vote was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

So as it suggests: Warning: extract() [function.extract]: First argument should be an array

Try following:

```
$arr = check($_SESSION['user_id'], $topicId);
if(is_array($arr)) {
  extract($arr);
  echo $against;
  echo $support;
} else {
  echo $arr;
}
```